# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(OutputFileName) works on local machine but not in webserver - vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation

Dear I have created a function in vb.net and asp.net application in which

**(1)-** from the front end , user selects multiple file names (via checkbox) listed in a page (list.aspx) and clicks export button to see all the documents in one single pdf file **(2)-** the system grab those documents from database ,**(3)-** the system converts them in to pdf file format and **(4)-** the system merge those pdf files into a single pdf file and **(5)-** the system display it as ideally in a iframe.

From the list.aspx page when some one clicks export cv it executes this code

```
window.location.href = 'export-cvs.aspx?v=' + vid + '&a=' + appids.toString();
```

in the export-cvs.aspx page the following code executes

```
<object id="cvFrame" width="100%" height="500px" type="application/pdf"  data="preview-bulk-cv.ashx?v=<%= Vacancy.ID%>&a=<%= Request("a") %>"></object>
```

The Main code is in preview-bulk-cv.ashx page and it is as below.

```
Public Class PDFMerge : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest


Dim vacancy = New Vacancy(context.Request("v"))
Dim sourceFiles = New List(Of String)()


For Each docPath As String In From row As DataRow In DB.GetData("query").Rows Select HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/documents") & "\" & Left(guid, 1) & "\" & Right(guid, 1) & "\" & guid & "." & System.IO.Path.GetExtension(row.Item("originalfilename")).ToLower().Substring(1)

   cnt+=1

    Dim epath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Downloads") & "\"  & Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss") & "_" & cnt.Tostring & ".pdf"

    Converter.ConvertDocument(docPath, epath)
    If File.Exists(epath) Then
        sourceFiles.Add(epath)
    End If

Next

Dim OutputFileName As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Downloads") & "\" & vacancy.Title.Replace(" ", "_") & ".pdf"

PDFMerge.MergeFiles(OutputFileName, sourceFiles.ToArray)
Dim mPDFFile As FileStream = File.OpenRead(OutputFileName)
Dim mPDFFileBuffer(mPDFFile.Length - 1) As Byte
mPDFFile.Read(mPDFFileBuffer, 0, mPDFFileBuffer.Length)
mPDFFile.Close()

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(OutputFileName)


context.Response.Clear()
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & OutputFileName)
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", mPDFFileBuffer.Length)
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(mPDFFileBuffer, 0, mPDFFileBuffer.Length)
mPDFFileBuffer = Nothing
context.Response.Flush()
context.Response.End()



End Sub
End Class
```

You can see in my above code.  I have used the following line to open the final pdf document.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(OutputFileName)
```

This code works in local server but doesnot work in webserver. i.e the pdf file opens when i run the application on localhost. but the pdf file doesnot open when the application is stored on webserver and the webapplication is runned as webapplication from any machine. I have checked in the webserver that the files are being created merged properly in the right folder.

the webserver is built with windows. its windows version 2008 r2 and IIS version 7.5

how can I make it work?

Comment: Are you expecting the PDF to open on your client machine? That code will try to run on the server and the person using the website will never see it.

Comment: yes I am expecting to open the file in client machine. Can you please then provide the code that will open the pdf on client machine. can i display the pdf file on a iframe in export-cv.aspx page? can you please advice how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this example is C# but here is a link demonstrating streaming a PDF to the browser.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654

You might also investigate Response.WriteFile() to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Response.WriteFile() is working now . although the pdf is not displaying in iframe but but it is downloading now.

Comment: <iframe id="bulkcv" width="0" height="0" style="border: none;" frameborder="0"  type="application/pdf" src="preview-bulk-cv.ashx?v=<%= Vacancy.ID%>&a=<%= Request("a") %>"></iframe>   i have replaced the line of code in export-cvs.aspx page with the above code and now it is working.